How to transform elliptic integrals with conjugate complex variables into a linear sum of elliptic integrals with real variables and imaginary units?
How to transform elliptic integrals with conjugate complex variables into a linear sum of elliptic integrals with real variables and imaginary units?
It seems wrong to use the addition formula directly.
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\frac{5+2i}{4}}\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\sqrt{(1-t^{2})(1-({\raise{0.8pt}\scriptsize{\frac{\sqrt{10}-\sqrt{2}+2\sqrt{\sqrt{5}-1}}{4}}})^{2}t^{2})}}-\int_{0}^{\frac{5-2i}{4}}\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\sqrt{(1-t^{2})(1-({\raise{0.8pt}\scriptsize{\frac{\sqrt{10}-\sqrt{2}+2\sqrt{\sqrt{5}-1}}{4}}})^{2}t^{2})}}\approx1.724021 i
\end{align*}
Note that the transformed elliptic integral modulus k becomes the complementary modulus.
\begin{align*}
=i\int_{0}^{???}\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\sqrt{(1-t^{2})(1-({\raise{0.8pt}\scriptsize{\frac{\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{10}+2\sqrt{\sqrt{5}-1}}{4}}})^{2}t^{2})}}+i\int_{0}^{???}\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\sqrt{(1-t^{2})(1-({\raise{0.8pt}\scriptsize{\frac{\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{10}+2\sqrt{\sqrt{5}-1}}{4}}})^{2}t^{2})}}
\end{align*}
Directly using the elliptic integral addition formula, the elliptic integral with real variables obtained is not equal to the original integral
\begin{gather*}
Z=\frac{X \sqrt{\left(1-Y^2\right)(1-({\raise{0.8pt}\scriptsize{\frac{\sqrt{10}-\sqrt{2}+2\sqrt{\sqrt{5}-1}}{4}}})^2Y^2)}-Y\sqrt{\left(1-X^2\right)(1-({\raise{0.8pt}\scriptsize{\frac{\sqrt{10}-\sqrt{2}+2\sqrt{\sqrt{5}-1}}{4}}})^2X^2)}}{1-({\raise{0.8pt}\scriptsize{\frac{\sqrt{10}-\sqrt{2}+2\sqrt{\sqrt{5}-1}}{4}}})^2 X^2 Y^2}\approx0.571777 i\\
\\
X=\frac{5+2i}{4}\\
Y=\frac{5-2i}{4}\\
\end{gather*}
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{Z}\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\sqrt{(1-t^{2})(1-({\raise{0.8pt}\scriptsize{\frac{\sqrt{10}-\sqrt{2}+2\sqrt{\sqrt{5}-1}}{4}}})^{2}t^{2})}}\approx0.544071 i
\end{align*}
